# How to put the page break after every division?

Tags: html, css

I have used a style property inside a div to put a page break after it. But its not working.
`style="page-break-after:always"`
I have also used the CSS in media print as:

```
@media print {
h3{page-break-after: always;
  }
}

<div class="row" style="margin-top:50px;">
    <div class="col-lg-12"> 
        <div id="AverageTime">
        <h3>Hello world.</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Kindly help.Thanks

Comment: What class you are giving to each of your `<div>` s?

Comment: can you show us your html code.? if possible.

Comment: Where is `Class="page-break"` ??

Comment: class="row" i have given.

Answer (score 1):

Here, I guess that you missed to give a `page-break` class to your divs.
So, I'm demonstrating you exact way to implement it.

**Your CSS** will be like this

```
   @media print {
            .page-break { 
                         display: block; 
                         page-break-before: always; 
                }
   }
```

**Your Html** Will be like this.

```
  //Content
  <div class="page-break"></div>
  //Content
```

I Hope it helps.